# Process Binary Data at HTTP client which have conversion need from little endian to big endian

Tags: javascript, httpclient, endianness

I am using a low-power embedded device as an HTTP server to get the data from the field (ex. current sensor). And then these data are sent to the  HTTP client on the Desktop or any other computing device. The data format I am trying to use to send sensor readings from the HTTP server to the Client is binary-octet (Directly from the memory buffer in the server). The data are getting received properly at HTTP client but it's in little-endian format.
Can anyone suggest how to convert/process these data to get the integer format array?

Example Data:
At server,

```
uint16 dataarray[4096] = {0x1101,0x1102,.............,0x20EF};
```

Data received at http client

```
Bytearray=011102110311..............EF20;
```

Data format needed is -->

```
int16array[4096] = {4353,4354,.............,8431};
```

to perform some operation at client, download, and plot.

Comment: If your client is also little endian, you could simply cast or memcpy, given you have considered alignment and stuff. But the bullet-prove way is an explicit conversion, in the sense of "first + 0x100 * second".

Comment: It is unclear - presumably this being HTTP `Bytearray=011102110311...` is ASCII text, so you have to convert to `uint16`?  What language?

Comment: Note that the "data at server" and "data format needed" are identical - that fact that one is in hex notation and the other in decimal is irrelevant - that is just alternative _presentation_ of the same integer values for human consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The `Bytearray` data is in little-endian order to pack that into a `uint16_t` at the receiver regardless of the endian-ness of the platform:

```
for( size_t b = 0; b < byte_data_length; b += 2 )
{
    //                LSB            MSB
    int16array[b/2] = Bytearray[b] | (Bytearray[b+1] << 8) ;
}
```

Treat that as pseudo-code since you have provided no indication of implementation language or provided much context.

If the data `Bytearray` in you question is an ASCII string of characters representing binary in ASCII hex, then you will of course first need to convert the string to a byte array.  Again as pseudo-code:

```
for( size_t h = 0; h < hex_data_length; h += 2 )
{
    Bytearray[h/2] = 0 ;
    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        char hex_digit = hex_data[h + i] ;
        
        if( hex_digit >= '0' && hex_digit <= '9' )
        {
            Bytearry[h/2] |= (hex_digit - '0') << 4 * i ;
        }
        else
        {
            Bytearry[h/2] |= (hex_digit - 'A') << 4 * i ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is in JavaScript. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @KuldeepShivran then you need to mention that in the question to tags.  Also the [embedded] tag is likely inappropriate since the solution you seek is not implemented on the embedded system.